# Which is better for my scenario - WCF or WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, xamarin, webapi

My case is - I'm developing a system that help a car service to communicate with their customers and vice versa. There will be two products - a mobile app written in Xamarin.Forms and a web page in ASP.Net - both doing same things more or less, an alternative. The database will be hosted on SQL Server. And now I'm confused about the "middle" layer. I have been reading a lot about WCF and WebAPI and I still can't figure out which is better for me. Any suggestions for this scenario?

Comment: Usually _which is better_ questions are closed as opinion based or seeking for recommendations. So I can only give you an opinion. I suggest to choose the later (WebAPI) and Net.Core because they are more supported now, but there are a lot of factors to evaluate. ISP support? Familiarity with the framework? Time constraints? Sorry but you can see why these questions are off-topic. The answers inevitably are imprecise and their usefulness fade with time

Comment: I **strongly strongly strongly** recommend against using WCF for any new projects. **WCF IS OBSOLETE**. WCF was built all around SOAP, XML and the WS-* family of 
"Enterprise-y" web-services standards which are all-but irrelevant today (SAML still lives on in some way...). WCF only supports RESTful-esque services and JSON through an adapter layer which is a pain to configure (Service Contracts, Behaviors, Endpoints, all configured in web.config with redundant and overlapping concerns).

Comment: All of the claimed "benefits" of WCF's built-in auto-generation of client-code all apply to RESTful web-services using Swagger - the WCF client-generation code remains largely unchanged since 2008 - the `svcutil` program doesn't even support the post-2010 TAP (`Task`-based Asynchronous Pattern), instead [it generates legacy `iAsyncResult` or Event-based asynchronous code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-call-wcf-service-operations-asynchronously) which is incompatible with modern development platforms and just archaic and _alien_ in .NET Core.

Comment: In short: **DO NOT USE WCF FOR NEW PROJECTS!** (I'm shouting because it's infuriating to see someone fail to do the minimal amount of research needed to see that WCF is completely dead and obsolete). Just google around for "wcf obsolete" to see hundreds of blog articles over the past 8 years celebrating the fact WCF is irrelevant (because ASP.NET Web API was released around 2012).

Comment: @Dai I did more than "minimal amount of research" and I didn't notice anywhere that it's dead. Anyway, thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Better" is always a hard question to answer. So, that's my disclaimer.

WebAPI is currently pretty standard, and quite easy. It allows for simple REST api's - although these are very doable with WCF as well.

The main difference between WCF and Web API

#### Web API

is, well Web (HTTP) - almost every language supports it, it's relatively light weight.

#### WCF

It's big - HTTP is just one of the options for binding. It's ideal for enterprise wide connectivity solutions. For example - reusing your logic for HTTP bindings and or message queueing.

---

One nice feature of WCF is that, at least for C#, it generates client libraries and models for you. It comes with Visual Studio (note: see warning). For the WebAPI, you might need to create the client libraries yourself - which basically be a lot of HTTP calls.

If you want it simple - WebAPI has very good support and can be implemented easily from any language - the clients and models are pretty straight forward - but usually you do need to code them yourself, unless you use OpenAPI spec and some toolkits.

---

#### Warning

The generated WCF libraries, might or might not be compatible with the framework (Mono, Xamarin, Core, etc.)  you are using. As @Dai mentions, the WCF client library generation might be outdated. Although I do not know if there are more open source tools available to extract clients from the WSDL. So, you should try if your client is compatible first.

For Web API client generation, you can look at tools like Swaggerhub. Do note: you need to define the spec in your application (or provide it explicitly)
See: https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/

---

#### The advise (obviously just an opinion)

If you don't need the full package of WCF, the extensive binding capabilities and such, I would go for the WebAPI variant.

If you combine it with Swagger (OpenAPI spec), you'll get a pretty open and easy to use API available for a broad variety of languages.

For more info on swagger/swashbuckle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. Exactly, what I like the most about WCF is the fact that is so much easier (or less work) to implement/use as far as C# apps are concerned. And this tempts me towards it.

Comment: @Michal_Drwal: do note: I am not sure if Xamarin is able to use the WCF clients - if you're going to use that, you might want to do a POC first.

Comment: It works with Xamarin, both of them work. I checked it and that's why I got confused. I'm new to services and I'm just looking for some "deal breaking" factors that will stop me using this or that technology.

Comment: "One nice feature of WCF is that, at least for C#, it generates client libraries and models for you. It comes with Visual Studio. For the WebAPI, you might need to create the client libraries yourself - which basically be a lot of HTTP calls." - **this is untrue in practice**. WCF's client-generation code remains frozen in time since 2008, whereas the .NET developer ecosystem has a whole wealth of tools and libraries for auto-generating Swagger definitions and clients for RESTful web-services.

Comment: @Dai: Good point, although I tried to address this with my warning note. I'll try to elaborate more on it. On side note about Swagger (aka: Open API spec); it does not come out of the box in the templates - you do need to implement it first.

Comment: @Dai: updated, I hope you will appreciate it more like this

Comment: @Michal_Drwal: do note: I would use WebAPI most likely myself... but I am already pretty comfortable with those techniques.

Comment: @Stefan ASP.NET Core comes with some-degree of Swagger/OpenAPI support out-of-the-box, but [Microsoft provides full guidance on using Swagger/OpenAPI fully](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: @Stefan I've calmed down now and I must apologize for being so rude to everyone. By way of explanation - I used to work on WCF projects between 2009 and 2013 and I wasted so much of my life trying to use WCF as the basis for a RESTful web-service - there's just so many gotchas and under-documented parts of WCF - especially its gargantuan configuration model. When I worked at Microsoft in DevDiv I asked around for the story of WCF and I gathered the "configuration over code" idea was a mistake - and we see the about-turn in ASP.NET Core which is all about "configuration through code" instead.

Comment: @Dai: Thank you for your kind words. I feel your pain ... I have been coding for 2 decades as well - some investments are pretty worthless these days ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the opinions - I'm new to that, so I wanted to be more aware. I think I'll go with WebAPI then, at least I'll learn something new.